# Pass Lua table by stringified reference instead of directly by reference

Tags: lua, reference, lua-table

I want to pass a lua reference to another function without actually using assignment `=` but something like `loadstring`.

```lua
local myTable = { test="Hello" }
local myTableStringified = tostring(myTable) -- table: 0xref
print(myTableStringified)
local myTableUnstringified = loadstring(myTableStringified)
print(myTableUnstringified) -- nil but should show table: 0xref
```

As seen above, this won't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use one of the modules that provide [serialization](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization).

Keep in mind that `loadstring` returns a function that needs to be called, so to get the table back you need to use `loadstring(myTableStringified)()`.